# BR tag with php variables are not working

Tags: php, html

This is the problem that i am facing.

```
$value1=100;
$value2=5;
```

if i multiply the value like this, with a br tag at the end,

```
echo $value1*=$value2."</br>";
```

br tag is not working at all.

Can anyone help?.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Why did u down voted this?.is it prohibited to test the limitation of php?.is it bad to try new things?

Comment: @DamForums did you tried my code here http://writecodeonline.com/php/ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do :

```
echo ($value1*=$value2) . "<br/>";
```

Comment: Yep! It's shorter than mine :)

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be `<br />` instead of `</br>`

Also, show the 'br' with another echo

```
echo $value1*=$value2;
echo "<br />".'should appear at new line';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$value1=100;
$value2=5;

$value1*=$value2;

echo $value1 . '<br />';
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<?php

  $value1=100;
  $value2=5;

  echo $value1*=$value2;
  echo '<br/>';
  echo 'test me'; // to check BR tag is working or not

?>
```

Comment: yes it is working.but i tried to do this on one line.

Comment: So, you can try @putvande 's solution

Comment: @MarioJohnathan lol he tried putvande's solution and accept your answer

Comment: @DamForums NP finaly you found the solution

Answer (score 1):

For php7:

```
echo "Message" . "\n";
```